# New grooming system load problem

Tags: geometry-nodes, scene

When I load a test project from blender website for 3.5 version, presenting a few heads' hair styles created, I don't see any hair. I'm using 3.5 blender. What could be the reason? It just doesn't load, though these curves are present in the outliner.

And it's similar if I try to make smt myself. I create a plane, I add fur to it so a plane turns into a fuzzy curpet quickly. I see curve modifiers present, I see geometry nodes and I see that hair visually in the viewport. That's sweet, I save it and then I load that scene again and the next what happens- I see the plane, but there's no hair whatsoever. I do see curves present in the outliner, but nothing else. Even If select it, nothing is selected in the viewport. geometry nodes are still present in these invisible curves, but nothing changes if I tweak it as well.

I don't get it. Could anyone please help me find a proper answer to what is going on?

I'm using blender 3.5. I even tried deleting Addons I use but nothing changed.

I really wish I could find an answer myself, but I feel like giving up already and coming back to old grooming system since it's stable particle system and never fails when loaded.

Comment: It could be a bug. Have you tried a start with factory settings? In Blender's directory (Windows) there is a *blender_factory_startup.cmd* file. With it, you can start Blender with factory settings and no 3rd party add-ons active. It also creates log files.

Comment: I did try this and surprisingly no result. I mean I didn't delete all plugins and other scripts that contain addons from my folders, but in blender itself I did click to go back to factory settings. It didn't help. And it's blender 3.5. 
I'm not sure why it didn't help, though it's obviously should have..